# Python error: cannot add integral value to Timestamp without freq

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I am trying calculate the difference between two dates to get a number that is an integer difference (in days) between the two dates, but I get the following error: "Cannot add integral value to Timestmp without freq".  Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

import os
import datetime
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def main():
    count = 0
    df = pd.DataFrame([])
    start = datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 11)
    end = datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 27)
    index_date = datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 11)
    symbols_list = ['ORCL', 'TSLA', 'IBM','YELP', 'MSFT']
    length = len(symbols_list)
    for num, ticker in enumerate(symbols_list, start=1):
        f = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)['Adj Close']
        f.ix[index_date]
        if count == 0:
            f = f.to_frame().reset_index()
            df = f
            df.columns = ['Date', ticker]
            length_df = len(df)
            sDate = df.iloc[:,-2]  # Date data list
            print ('sDate[0] is: ', (sDate[0]))
            j = 0
            while j < len(sDate[j] - 1):
                date_delta = timedelta(sDate[j] - index_date)
                j += 1
```

It crashes at the last line:

```
date_delta = timedelta(sDate[j] - index_reference_date)
```

The error message is: "Cannot add integral value to Timestmp without freq".

I cannot understand what the problem is. The data types are:

```
sDate[0] is:     2017-10-06 00:00:00, and 
index_date is:   2017-10-11 00:00:00 
index_date type is:  <type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

But note that:

```
sDate[0] type is:  <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

So: Maybe the problem is here?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a typing error on this line:

```
while j < len(sDate[j] - 1):
```

`sDate` is a date data list, thus `sDate[j]` is a date (probably of type `pandas.tslib.Timestamp`) and it's length does not make sense. So you probably want something like:

```
while j < len(sDate) - 1:
```

Maybe it's more appropriate to use a for loop, something like:

```
for dat in sDate[:-1]:
```

Edit: and then you need the thinks I wrote to the first answer.

Comment: I made the changes suggested and got:
    j = 0
        while j < len(sDate - 1):  
        date_delta = timedelta(microseconds=(sDate[j] - 
              index_reference_date).delta) 
        j += 1

Error: incompatible type for a datetime/timedelta operation [__sub__]

Comment: Read carefully my friend. `len(sDate) - 1` (which is what I wrote) is not the same as `len(sDate - 1)` from your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing may be the type of the difference `sDate[j] - index_reference_date` and how to pass it to `timedelta` constructor.

I believe this could be the solution:

```
date_delta = timedelta(microseconds=(sDate[j] - index_reference_date).delta)
```

Comment: Well, that throws this error: "ValueError: Cannot add integral value to timestamp without freq".